# Advance Topics in Geometry: What betweenness relations follow (by definition) among these four points?

Tags: geometry

Problem: Suppose that in a certain metric geometry, points A, B, C, and D are collinear and AB = 6, AC = BC = 3, BD = CD = 1, and AD = 2. What betweenness relations follow (by definition) among these four points? I am trying to see if I am solving this problem correctly and if I am using the correct definition.

So I am working on this problem as practice for my upcoming exam. The book I am using is David C. Kay's College Geometry A discovery Approach. I used the definition of betweenness in a metric space to solve this problem. Betweenness A-B-C of points states " We say B is between A and C if AB+BC=AC." on page 80. There is an example I followed on page 80-81.

In order to show if between relation exist I used the definition above.

{A,B,C} -> AC=3,BC=3, and AB=6. AC+BC=AB, 3+3=6. Therefore, A-C-B holds.
{A,B,D} -> AB=6, BD=1, and AD=2. No betweenness holds.
{A,C,D} -> AC=3, CD=1. and AD=2. CD+AD=AC, 1+2=3. Therefore, A-D-C holds.
{B,C,D} -> BC=3, DC=1, and BD=1. No betweenness holds.

Thus, we can conclude that the only betweenness relation exist is A-C-B and A-D-C.

Please let me know if I am going in the right direction for this problem.

Comment: How did you get AB=6? Also doesn't A-C-D go against A-D-C? [but you concluded both]

Comment: It was given that AB=6. I also look at the axiom for distance that states " For all points A and B, AB=BA."

Comment: Page 78 from book.

Comment: I am sorry that was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Yes it seems alright!

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: With BD=CD=1 and BC=3, you must not be using the standard notion of metric.

Comment: I am thinking it is not but my professor created the problems.